# Xcode "The program being debugged is not being run" error

Tags: iphone, debugging, profile, provisioning

I saw the other question here with the similar error yet their fixes did not help.

I have a jailbroken iphone 3.1.2, and I just purchased apple's $99 dollar thing and I'm trying to make it so I can debug my apps on the phone. The device installs but will not run when clicked build and go.

If I click on the icon made on the iphone it works.

Any ideas? I already uninstalled and reinstalled my provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to fix it without doing this but I took a gamble and downloaded the latest SDK only available for paying developers and that fixed the issue. Won't let me make the base sdk anything below 4 however.

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens, i usally fix it by unplugging and plugging in my device, or shutting down xcode and bringing it back..

Comment: Yeah same here... the cable sometimes screws up and gives me that error if I move the cable at all during build-n-go

Comment: I've tried that as well with no luck. I ran console the same time that I was running the program and got this output:


run
Running…
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 194.
Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 194.
The program being debugged is not being run.
The program being debugged is not being run.